# How to extract location from each hover element?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, nlp

I am trying to extract the location of each commenters when hovered to the commenter's name from [this website](https://interesting.quora.com/Don-t-stay-in-a-relationship-when-you-aren-t-ready-to-commit-fully-https-www-quora-com-Is-it-bad-that-I-want-to-end). However, it kept outputting the location of poster.

This is my draft code:

```
cmts = []

all_comments = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="q-box qu-ml--small qu-flex--auto"]')

for comments in all_comments:
    cmter = comments.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[class="q-box Link___StyledBox-t2xg9c-0 dFkjrQ puppeteer_test_link qu-color--gray_dark qu-cursor--pointer qu-hover--textDecoration--underline"]')

    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(cmter).perform()
    time.sleep(1.5)
    try:
        cmterloc = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="q-text qu-truncateLines--2"][contains(., "Lives in") or contains(., "Lived in")]/span/span'))
    except:
        cmterloc = 'None'
    cmt = comments.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="q-text"]').text

    if cmt != '' and [cmter.text, cmterloc, cmt] not in cmts:
        cmts.append([cmter.text, cmterloc, cmt])
```

The expected output will be something like this:
[author_name1, author_location1, comment1]

[author_name2, author_location2, comment2]

[author_name3, author_location3, comment3]

Answer (score 1):

That happened, because you're not searching location from user modal root.
I changed a bit your locators and logic, try this code.

```js
cmts = []
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class*="q-box comment_and_ad_container"] [class=q-flex]'))
    )
   
    allComments = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class*="q-box comment_and_ad_container"] [class=q-flex]')

for comments in all_comments:
    hoverBox = comments.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[aria-haspopup='dialog'] img")
    cmt = comments.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class='q-box qu-userSelect--text']").text

    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(hoverBox).perform()
    dialog = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[role=dialog]"))
    )
    try:
        cmterloc = dialog.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(.,'Lives in') or contains(., 'Lived in')]/span[contains(@class, 'q-text')]").text
    except:
        cmterloc = 'None'
    cmter = dialog.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, 'profile')]//span/span").text
    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(hoverBox, -100, 0).perform()


    if cmt != '' and [cmter, cmterloc, cmt] not in cmts:
        cmts.append([cmter, cmterloc, cmt])
```

Comment: I wrote this logic on Java and it worked for me. I adopted it to Python and your code blindly, so there can be minor syntax errors. :)